# How do I create a working infoWindow and use event listener within it?

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I am trying to create an infowindow that shows a piece of text `'this is my marker'` when the map is loaded but it is not showing. I'm using the exact same code from my lecturer's [powerpoint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/powerpoint) but idk where I'm going wrong.

```
function initialize(){
    
    let mapDiv = document.getElementById('map');
    
    let mapOptions = {
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(Coords.lat,Coords.lng),
        zoom: 4,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.HYBRID
    };
    
    let marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(40.72,-74.00),
        map: map,
        title: 'I am here!',
        icon: svgMarker
    });
    
    var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({content: 'This is my marker'});
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function()
    {
        infoWindow.open(map,this);
    });
    
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), mapOptions);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You have the sequence slightly wrong. You are attempting to add both the marker & the infoWindow before you have created the map. Perhaps if you re-sequence your code a little like this:

```
/* assumed that a global variable exists */
let Coords={
    lat:41,
    lng:-75
};


function initialize(){
    let options = {
        center: new google.maps.LatLng( Coords.lat,Coords.lng ),
        zoom: 4,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.HYBRID
    };

    let map = new google.maps.Map( document.getElementById("map"), options );
  
    let marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(40.72,-74.00),
        map: map,
        title: 'I am here!'
        /*,
        icon: svgMarker
        */
    });
  
    let infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow( { content:'This is my marker' } );
        infoWindow.open( map, marker );
      
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function(e) {
        infoWindow.open(map,this);  
    });
};
```

To get the infoWindow to appear when the map is loaded you should call the `open` method and if you supply the previously created marker as the second argument it will appear in the correct location.